# writing a library class properly

Tags: asp.net, dll, webforms

This is my very first library class that i am writing and i feel like i need to load up on that topic but cannot find the best sources. I have a web forms project that uploads a pdf and creates a qrcode for it and places it in the document. I need to create a library but don't know where to start or the exact structure. Every method it's own subclass in the library class? or can i have them all in one and what is a professional way of going about this.

This is party of my web forms application that i need to create a library for:

```
void UpdateStudentSubmissionGrid()
    {
        var usr = StudentListStep2.SelectedItem as User;
        var lib = AssignmentListStep2.SelectedItem as Library;
        if (usr == null || lib == null) return;

        using (var dc = new DocMgmtDataContext())
        {
            var subs =
                (from doc in dc.Documents
                     where doc.OwnedByUserID == usr.ID && doc.LibraryID == lib.ID
                     select new {DocID = doc.ID, Assignment = doc.Library.Name, Submitted = doc.UploadDT})
                  .OrderByDescending(c => c.Submitted)
                  .ToList();

            StudentSubmissionGrid.DataSource = subs;


        }
    }
```

How do i start with this method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the looks of things you are using this function for a single webpage. You can call that function from any event i.e. user hits submit button. On the. Click the button and it will create a onclick event. Call the code from inside there UpdateStudentSubmissionGrid();  Just make sure the function is not nested inside another event or function. Webforms is already a class, you are just placing a function within the class.

Comment: Thanks for the info and help. Also do you happen to know great sites or tutorials about creating dlls and how to use them. I am very new and feel a little lost to knowing where to look or what to read.

Comment: Microsoft has plenty of examples on their website. The msdn books are pretty good as well. however, the best way for me to learn new concepts is to find some open source classes that are simple and tinker with them. however I would suggest that you build classes with WinForms because they are easier to debug.